# EPPPlus cannot open RDLC rendered to EXCELOPENXML

Tags: rdlc, epplus

Does anyone have any idea , or even a solution, to open an xlsx file using EPPlus created from an rdlc report.

At the moment, when I try to do this I get an null exception when I try to access the worksheets.

```
// filename is the xlsx file created by exported rdlc to excel
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(filename);
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

// I get error here
pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("New Sheet");
```

Comment: What is the exception?   If you open the file in excel does it work?  If you save in excel and then try opening with EPPlus do you still get the exception?

Comment: I get a null value exception when I try to access worksheets object. If I open and save in excel it works fine - unfortunately I don't have excel / office on web server.

Comment: Is your intention to use the exported file as a template or do you want to modify the file by adding on to it?

Comment: I was hoping to add to it. Some reports are generated direct from reportviewer and some are generated direct from EPPlus. The customer wanted them combining into single excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intention is to add onto the file you are using the wrong constructor. The one you are using now is for creating a new package off of a template. The on your want is this (without the extra Boolean) which will open the file directly:

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
```

---

**Response to Comments**

@A.Ellwood  I just tried it with the file you posted and it works fine for me.  Here is the code I used:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RDLC_Test()
{
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int)),
        new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (object))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = i;
        row[1] = i*10;
        row[2] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Report1.xlsx");

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd initially tried with that constructor. Same problem exists. I've updated the original question to reflect this.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is with the way ReportViewer forms the open xml document. Excel is probably more forgiving than EPPlus. I've had the file (and the one opened and saved in Excel) open in the Open XML Productivity tool to try and compare differences but this is tricky because excel appears to make a number of changes.

Comment: @A.Ellwood Maybe post the file somewhere so others can take a look.  What I usually do in these situations is rename the file to .zip and do a before and after compare between the xml in a text editor (Notepad++ plus the XML Tools plugin is extremely helpful for this for formatting).  Once you figure out the difference you can probably adjust the xml in the EPPlus object manually assuming it is not too serious a change.

Comment: Thanks ernie, am try to do comparison now. File is uploaded onto codeplex http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15369

Comment: it transpires I was using version 3.0.3 of EPPlus, when I use latest version I can open fil ok. Lesson is always use latest version. Thanks for your help